# state variables are not saved on private chain

Tags: blockchain, remix, testing

I set up a private blockchain and it works.
I tried a very simple contract, it was mined successfully, but the state variables are not saved in the blockchain or this is what it seems. The getter functions returns no value.

What is wrong here?

The contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract MyContract{
uint constant value = 90;
string constant mystr = "Hello";

function getValue() constant returns(uint){
    return value;
}

function getMystr() constant returns(string){
    return mystr;
}
}
```

The result in solidity browser (run offline, web3 provider connected to localhost:8545):

[image]

Comment: I test everything is ok. did you start rpc and connect `http://localhost:8545`?

Comment: Yes. It is connected, the contract is mined. I see the message in solidity browser: Waiting for transaction to be mined..., after that I start mining in geth console: miner.start() and it is mined.

Comment: It's so weird. I'm sure that the state variables are saved. do you change Environment from `Web3 provider` to `JavaScript VM` to try it ?

Comment: try to desactivate all the other plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried exactly the same and it gave the correct values as follow.

[image]

Apparently there's nothing you are doing wrong. What I can only suggest is give it a try toggling between Web3 provider and JavaScript VM and select again the web3 provider and try deploying the contract again.

Comment: Somehow it worked. I think the problem was with the provider. It should be web3. Thank you.